# Make an file path in Unix filesystem actually point to a program

Tags: linux, file, unix, filesystems

I'm currently using a piece of software (let's call it ThirdPartyApp) that reads files from a certain directory on my PC. I want to make my own software (call it MyApp) that generates files for ThirdPartyApp. When ThirdPartyApp tries to load `/path/to/somefile`, instead of `somefile` getting read from the hard drive, I want MyApp to get called and generate bytes in real time. This is similar to how reading from, say, `/dev/urandom` doesn't actually load a file called `urandom`, but instead loads the output of a random generator.

So, my question is, is this even possible to do in userspace? If so, what is this called? I'm not asking for a recommendation of a specific library or anything like that; I just need to know what to google to find info about doing something like this. Oh, and I only care about making this work on Linux, if that's a limiting factor. Thanks!

Comment: check out fuse file system :  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need, thank you!

Comment: Also check out [named pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe). Btw, if you control starting this ThirdPartyApp then you can simply run MyApp just before that.

Comment: Perfect, thanks @Kenney.

Answer (score 0):

check out fuse file system : [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) – Matt Joyce

Also check out [named pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe). Btw, if you control starting this ThirdPartyApp then you can simply run MyApp just before that. – Kenney